# User registration and login possible with just flask and sqlite3?

Tags: python, flask, sqlite

I am trying to build a web app with flask using just flask and sqlite3, and was wondering if this is possible, and if you could direct me to any examples of how to set up this database.
I have built the html pages for redirect and set up the / redirects but just don't know how to set up this database.
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If you look in [flask wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/flask/info) you can find [Mega Tutorial](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-v-user-logins) which covers user authentication, registration and DB implementation. Note that posts asking for tutorials and examples instead of handling specific problems usually don't fit for SO :)

Answer (score 1):

the initial part of the Youtube video by JetBrains (creator of the famous PyCharm IDE) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2geC50roans may be able to help and explain to you on how to setup the database using flask, sqlite3 and SQLAlchemy, here is the snippet of the code:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy import Integer, Column, Text

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///pin.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


class Pin(db.Model):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = Column(Text, unique=False)
    image = Column(Text, unique=False)

db.create_all()
```